# How to consider gap at exit order in TradingView Pine code

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm trying to backtest a strategy at tradingview, but I'm having a problem that I'm not able to solve:
When price gaps my stop gain (SG) instead of close at open of the next candle, it still closes at SG and I don't know how to exit at open.

My code is this:

```
//@version=4
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
strategy("IFR2", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=10, initial_capital=10000, process_orders_on_close=true)

// Settings
oversold = input(25, "RSI oversold level", minval=1, maxval=100)
candleLookback = input(2, "Candle lookback", minval=1)
atrExitMultiplier = input(0.0, "ATR exit multiplier", step=0.1)
closeAfter = input(0, "Close trades after a certain number of candles (0 is disabled)")

// Calculation
ifr2 = rsi(close, 2)
inMarket = strategy.opentrades != 0
opened = strategy.opentrades[0] > strategy.opentrades[1]

// Range check
startYear = input(0, "Start backtesting year", minval=0)
startMonth = input(1, "Start backtesting month", minval=1)
inRange = startYear == 0 ? true : timestamp(startYear, startMonth, 1, 1, 1, 1) <= time_close

// Entry order
longCondition = crossunder(ifr2, oversold) and inRange
if longCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", true, comment="Entry")

// Exit order
exitPrice = highest(candleLookback) + atr(candleLookback) * atrExitMultiplier

plot(longCondition or inMarket ? exitPrice : na, "Exit price", color.white, style=plot.style_linebr, offset=1)
strategy.exit("Long", limit=exitPrice, comment="Exit")

// Exit order after X candles
if closeAfter and barssince(opened) >= closeAfter
    strategy.close_all(comment="It has been " + tostring(closeAfter) + " candle" + (closeAfter > 1 ? "s" : "")  + " since you entered")
```

This strategy resumes on an entry long when the indicator rsi(2) dips below the number 25, and an exit when the prices reaches the high of X candles (being 2/3 the ones that I'm trying to backtest).
This strategy also exits after X days (being 6 bars the number used).

Screenshot of an example of the mistake [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opUCt.png).
Price gaps the high of the red candle(exit point) but the script continues to consider the exit at the high.